# Why does only the German (Switzerland) Gboard layout have umlauts?

Tags: gboard

I was looking for a way to add umlaut keys to my German keyboard and found this workaround. I can't imagine why Google did not manage to include them in 7 major versions (I am using 7.1.1). Especially considering that Germany has a population 10 times the size of Switzerland.

**Is there a sensible (technical) reason why only the Swiss variation of the German keyboard has keys for the umlauts *ä*, *ü* and *ö*?**

Comment: Something must be wrong on your side then, because I use the German (Germany) layout all the time and umlauts can be accessed either by casually swiping or long-pressing the base characters (a, o and u).

Comment: You did not read my question properly. I am talking about dedicated keys.

Answer (score 1):

As of the latest version (8.0.5), Gboard supports dedicated keys for umlauts on *all* German keyboards.

However, they will only show on the *German* variant of the keyboard, instead of the default QWERTZ variant on some locales (e.g. Germany, Austria), excluding the exclusive Swiss variant on the Switzerland locale.